# Reversing the order of a sort

Tags: c++, sorting

Hello so I have my program that has to do with a college class schedule and it has a couple sorting functions we will deal with the ascending gpa function and descending gpa function.

This is the descending function and it functions properly:

```
void classSchedule::downGPA(classSchedule schedule[], int& numElems)
{
    classSchedule temp;
    int end;
    for (end = numElems - 1; end >= 0; end--)
    {
        for (int counter = 0; counter < end; counter++)
        {
            if (schedule[counter].classNumber == 000)
                counter++;
           if (schedule[counter].currentGPA < schedule[counter + 1].currentGPA)
           {

              temp = schedule[counter];
              schedule[counter] = schedule[counter + 1];
              schedule[counter + 1] = temp;
           }
       }
    }
    schedule->outputToConsole(schedule, numElems);

}
```

This is the ascending function and it displays nothing for some reason:

```
void classSchedule::upGPA(classSchedule schedule[], int& numElems)
{
    classSchedule temp;
    int end;
    for (end = numElems - 1; end >= 0; end--)
    {
        for (int counter = 0; counter < end; counter++)
         {
            if (schedule[counter].classNumber == 000)
                counter++;
           if (schedule[counter].currentGPA > schedule[counter + 1].currentGPA)
           {

              temp = schedule[counter];
              schedule[counter] = schedule[counter + 1];
              schedule[counter + 1] = temp;
           }
       }
    }
    schedule->outputToConsole(schedule, numElems);
}
```

I changed the sign and it doesnt display anything can anyone see why?

Edit:

As requested the output function

```
void classSchedule::outputToConsole(classSchedule currentSchedule[], int numElems)
{
    int i;
    cout << endl << "Dept" << "\t" << "Class Number\t" "Credit Hours" << "\t" << "Name"
         << "\t" << "Room Number" << "\tGPA"
         << endl << "----" << "\t------------" << "\t-------------   ----"
         << "\t-----------" << "\t---";
    for (i = 0; i < numElems; i++)
    {
        if (currentSchedule[i].displayOrNot == "FALSE")
            i++;
        if(currentSchedule[i].currentGPA == -1)
        {
            break;
        }
        cout << endl << currentSchedule[i].classDepartment << "         " << currentSchedule[i].classNumber << "    \t"
             << "      " << currentSchedule[i].creditHours << "    \t"
             << currentSchedule[i].teacherLastName << " " << currentSchedule[i].teacherFirstName
             << "\t" << currentSchedule[i].roomWingAndNumber << "\t" <<      currentSchedule[i].currentGPA;
    }

}
```

Comment: Why are you bubble sorting?  Use `std::sort` and stop it.  Plus I think I see fencepost bugs (reading past the end of the array).  Why is `numElem`s a non-const `int&`?  Why is `int end` created outside of its loop?  Why is `counter` incremented in the middle of the code in a frankly insane way?

Comment: @Yakk Using `std::sort()` `reverse_iterator` also may come in handy to 'ssolve the problem.

Comment: No matter how you are sorting: If you already have the list in ascending order: Simply reverse it to get it in descending order.  It is simpler to do and costs only O(n) – better than any comparison-based sorting algorithm can be.

Comment: What does your debugger show you is happening?

Comment: But for your current problem: If you want to bubble-sort in reverse, think of watching the algorithm in the mirror.  Not only do you have to “mirror” `<` to `>` but also what used to be the lower array boundary is now the upper and vice versa.

Comment: Oh wow, that last line is strange: `schedule->outputToConsole(schedule, numElems)` -- take the first element of the array, invoke a method `outputToSchedule` on it with a pointer to the first element of the array and length?

Comment: @Yakk The counter increment is because it kept giving me garbage at the first char of the first input so i made a entry that didnt need to be displayed

Comment: @5gon12eder are you serious?

Comment: @user2311215 you should show content of `outputToConsole()` but better MCVE

Comment: @Yakk "Why are you bubble sorting? Use std::sort and stop it." He is obviously a student. This is a silly question. He learns programming and teacher told him to implement sorting.

Comment: adding outputToConsole right now

Comment: @slava maybe the student is supposed to implement sorting.  Or maybe the student was told to sort, and tried to implement sorting in order to do it.  I cannot tell which is the case from the OP's question.

Comment: Yes I am a student but Im allowed to use any c++ function or library.  The reason I havent tried sort is because the reference page is confusing it uses vectors which I havent worked with I am not sure how to implement it for use with my class object

Comment: @Yakk then your first comment should not be "use std::sort and stop implementing bubble" but "if you do not have to implement bubble sort you better use std::sort"

Comment: @Slava Except I was right in the end.  I guessed the answer (and the OP could correct me if I was wrong in my guess) and followed through.  While abrupt, it worked.

Comment: This line seems wrong:`if (schedule[counter].classNumber == 000) counter++;`, you should rather do `continue` here instead of `counter++`. Similary in `if (currentSchedule[i].displayOrNot == "FALSE") i++;`, do `continue` instead of `i++`. By the way, you don't need three zeros, they mean 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a little helper that makes sorting by some derived value easy:

```
template<class F>
struct order_by_t {
  F f;
  template<class Lhs, class Rhs>
  bool operator()( Lhs const& lhs, Rhs const& rhs ) const {
    return f(lhs) < f(rhs);
  }
};
template<class F>
order_by_t< F > order_by( F f ) { return {std::move(f)}; }
```

You call `order_by( function )` and it returns a function object that takes values, and orders them by whatever the function returns.

So `order_by( function )` returns a function object that takes two things, and tells you if the left one is "less" than the right one according to the order that `function` tells you.

This is useful because C++'s standard library can be passed ordering function objects and use them for a whole bunch of reasons.

This helper makes writing `upGPA` pretty short:

```
void classSchedule::upGPA(classSchedule schedule[], int numElems) {
  classSchedule* start = &schedule[0];
  classSchedule* finish = start+numElems;
  std::sort( start, finish,
    order_by( [](classSchedule const& s){return s.currentGPA;} )
  );
}
```

`order_by( [](classSchedule const& s){return s.currentGPA;} )` is where the magic happens.

I'll unroll it.  A simpler way to write it is:

```
[](classSchedule const& lhs, classSchedule const& rhs){
  return lhs.currentGPA < rhs.currentGPA;
}
```

but I like my way.

`order_by` takes a function of one argument, and builds an ordering (a replacement for `<`).

It takes a function of type `A->B` (read it as "elements of type A to elements of type B") such that `B` is ordered (supports `<`), and produces a function of type `(A,A)->bool` that is an ordering on `A`s.  It does this by taking each argument, mapping it through the `A->B` map, then comparing the `B`s.

So `order_by` is of type `(A->B) -> (A,A) -> bool` that returns an ordering based off of the `A->B` function.

I find this projection -- of a type to an order -- is quite useful.  In this case, it may be overkill.

---

An easy implementation of `downGPA` -- sort up, then reverse:

```
void classSchedule::downGPA(classSchedule schedule[], int numElems) {
  upGPA(schedule, numElems);
  classSchedule* start = &schedule[0];
  classSchedule* finish = start+numElems;
  std::reverse( start, finish );
}
```

you could instead use reverse iterators, or use a negated order-by, or whatever.  But the above is simple and less bug prone.

The function `upGPA` and `downGPA` shouldn't `outputToConsole`.  Do that in a different step.  Printing is a different problem than reordering in upward or downward order.

The above uses C++11.  With gcc or clang, you may need to pass in a flag to enable support.

If you lack C++11, this will work:

```
template<class F>
struct order_by_t {
  F f;
  order_by_t(F in):f(in) {}
  order_by_t(order_by_t const& o):f(o.f) {}
  template<class Lhs, class Rhs>
  bool operator()( Lhs const& lhs, Rhs const& rhs ) const {
    return f(lhs) < f(rhs);
  }
};
template<class F>
order_by_t< F > order_by( F f ) { return f; }
int getCurrentGPA( classSchedule const& s ) {
  return s.currentGPA;
}
```

then:

```
void classSchedule::upGPA(classSchedule schedule[], int numElems) {
  classSchedule* start = &schedule[0];
  classSchedule* finish = start+numElems;
  std::sort( start, finish,
    order_by( getCurrentGPA )
  );
}
```

should work.

or even easier:

```
bool orderByCurrentGPA( classSchedule const& lhs, classSchedule const& rhs ) {
  return lhs.currentGPA < rhs.currentGPA;
}
void classSchedule::upGPA(classSchedule schedule[], int numElems) {
  classSchedule* start = &schedule[0];
  classSchedule* finish = start+numElems;
  std::sort( start, finish,
    orderByCurrentGPA
  );
}
```

which does the same thing. (I removed `order_by` here).

Comment: `order_by( [](classSchedule const& s){return s.currentGPA;}` what does this do I get the rest except for the template part. I understand what a template is but unsure what you did with that functin

Comment: I tried it and it works but can someone explain to me why it works?

Comment: `order_by` returns a function object -- an object with `operator()` overloaded.  You can use it like a function, but it holds state.  In this case, it holds the lambda closure passed in `[](classSchedule const& s){return s.currentGPA;}`, which is *another* function object.  `[](classSchedule const& s){return s.currentGPA;}` returns an object that takes a `classSchedule const&` and returns its `currentGpa` when called with `()` brackets.  See the function `getCurrentGPA` in the C++03 section?  It does that, basically.

Comment: I guess where I am confused is why you declare `template<class F>` twice and also confused on what `order_by_t(F in):f(in){}` does

Comment: @user `order_by_t` is a object template.  It is a type, like `struct foo { int x; }`, except it stores one copy of some passed in type `F`.  The C++03 constructor just copies a passed in `F` to be stored within the `order_by_t<F>` object.  Meanwhile, `order_by` is a *function* `template` -- a function, not an object.  It is used to create an `order_by_t` without having to say what the type the `order_by_t` is storing.  Function templates can deduce their template types from their arguments, while template *objects* cannot.  The `order_by_t<F>` is also callable, which adds to the confusion.

Comment: @user or explained the other way around: `order_by` takes an argument, determines its type `F`.  It then creates a `order_by_t<F>` to store an instance of the argument.  `order_by_t<F>` stores an instance of `F` called `f`.  It also exposes a two-argument `operator()` that lets `order_by_t<F>` be called like a function.  The `operator()` takes two arguments (of any kind), calls `f` on each of them, then returns `<` based off the values `f` returns.  In short, this lets you take a type and *order it by* some property of the type -- in this case, GPA.

Comment: I'll be honest Im still really confused. I am using the c++03 example. So we have a struct order_by_t inside of that is an unknown type named f also is a template of function order_by_t which takes the parameter of an unknown type. What does `:f(in) {}` do I understand f is an unknown type as is in

Comment: @user they are both the same type `F` guaranteed.  In this case, the type is a function pointer of type `int(*)(classSchedule const&)`.  `in` is a constructor argument, `f` is a field in the object, and `:f(in)` initializes the stored `f` with the value `in`.  I have written a simplified version with `order_by` removed -- the `order_by` code does the same thing as the new simple version.

Comment: so instead of this `template<class F>
order_by_t< F > order_by( F f ) { return f; }` i can use this `bool orderByCurrentGPA( classSchedule const& lhs, classSchedule const& rhs ) {
  return lhs.currentGPA < rhs.currentGPA;
}`?

Comment: @user23 yes.  `order_by` just writes that function for you from `return s.currentGPA;`

Comment: do i need this still `bool operator()( Lhs const& lhs, Rhs const& rhs ) const {
    return f(lhs) < f(rhs);
  }`

Answer (score 1):

You have couple issues with your sorting functions:

- Your loop condition is `counter < end` and you use [counter+1] as array index, you will go out of array boundary on the first iteration, suggestion change condition to `counter < end -1`
- Code `if (schedule[counter].classNumber == 000)` is dangerous and is not clear why you need it. Probably to avoid previous error

Coolprit seems to be this code:

```
if(currentSchedule[i].currentGPA == -1)
{
    break;
}
```

When you sort in descending order that record goes to the end and it works fine. But when you sort in ascending that record is in begining and you interrupt your loop. If you wantto skip records with GPA -1 replace `break` with `continue` in that code.